# SOLR 6.4.1 Suggester is stubbornly case-sensitive, how to make case-insensitive?

Tags: solr, autocomplete, case-insensitive, search-suggestion

I've tried everything under the sun (well it is called solr after all) to make solr Suggest case-insensitive, but it stubbornly continues to be case-sensitive.

This returns a suggestion of Mexican:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/autocomplete?suggest.q=Mex
```

This returns 0 results:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/autocomplete?suggest.q=mex
```

To further diagnose I tried a lower case /select search against my suggestions field, which successfully returned docs containing "Mexican":

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycollection/select?q=suggestions:mex*
```

But no such luck using lowercase with the Suggester. It's as though my `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>` has no effect when used by the Suggester.

I of course did a full config upload, collection reload, data re-index, and suggester rebuild before testing.  I'm on SOLR 6.4.1 running in cloud mode.  Any ideas?  Diagnostic tips?

**schema.xml**

```
 <fieldType name="textSuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
 </fieldType>

<field name="recipe" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

<field name="suggestions" type="textSuggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

<copyField source="recipe" dest="suggestions"/>
```

**solrconfig.xml**

```
  <searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">foodsuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">WFSTLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">suggestions</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
      <str name="storeDir">suggester_wfst_dir</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textSuggest</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/autocomplete" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="suggest">true</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">foodsuggester</str>
        <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      </lst>
      <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
      </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WFSTLookupFactory` apparently does not take the `suggestAnalyzerFieldType`  parameter and it is ignored. You could use the `AnalyzingLookupFactory`, which will analyze the text according to the `suggestAnalyzerFieldType`. So if you only want the lower case to be analyzed in the suggester you can use the `suggestAnalzerFieldType`, and indicate that you want to use the suggestText field type for analysis through the `suggestAnalyzerFieldType`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the **WFSTLookupFactory** lookup implmentation is case sensitive.

You can use **FuzzyLookupFactory**, if you don't have any specific reason for using **WFSTLookupFactory**.

```
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
```

Comment: Hey you're right!  FuzzyLookupFactory indeed does the trick!  The only thing is, I don't want fuzzy results, I only wanted exact case-insensitive suggestions.  This is big progress though, thanks.

Comment: OK got fuzzy factory returning only exact case-insensitive matches by adding  <str name="nonFuzzyPrefix">40</str> which means that the first 40 chars must match exactly (disregarding case).  It works perfectly and still allows for shorter exact matches such as in my case.